# Can't get the SelectedItem or SelectedIndex of a Combo Box

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm beginning to climb the walls here. I've filled a combo box with a list of items, and them I'm trying to find out which has been selected. I was also trying to set the combox box to auto selected the 0th item in the list. But that won't work either, I'm getting a binding expression path error on both GroupIndex and SelectedGroup. However I can't figure out what the problem is.

Combo Box Xaml:

```
<ComboBox     
Name="GroupComboBox"
SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=GroupIndex}"
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedGroup}"
DisplayMemberPath="Name"
SelectedValuePath ="Name"
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}"
Height="38"
HorizontalAlignment="Left"
Margin="159,115,0,0"
VerticalAlignment="Top"
Width="185"
FontSize="24" Text="Select a Group" IsEditable="False" IsReadOnly="False" />
```

Here is the code for filling the combo box.

```
    void webService_GroupListChanged(string response)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        IList<JSONGroup> listOfGroups = new List<JSONGroup>();

        listOfGroups = serializer.Deserialize<List<JSONGroup>>(response);

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>();

            foreach(JSONGroup group in listOfGroups)
            {
                Groups.Add(new Group(group.name, group.id));
            }

        }));
    }

    private int groupIndex;
    private int GroupIndex
    {
        get { return this.groupIndex; }
        set
        {
            if (this.groupIndex != value)
            {
                this.groupIndex = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("GroupIndex");
            }
        }
    }


    private Group selectedGroup;
    private Group SelectedGroup
    {
        get { return this.selectedGroup; }
        set
        {
            if (this.selectedGroup != value)
            {
                this.selectedGroup = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("SelectedGroup");
            }
        }
    }


    private ObservableCollection<Group> groups;
    public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups
    {
        get { return this.groups; }
        set
        {
            if (this.groups != value)
            {
                this.groups = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Groups");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you setting the DataContext? And if so, what to?

Comment: The datacontext of the view (a user control) is set to the viewmodel which the code above resides in. The binding for the actual list of items in the combo box works, so in theory the other two bindings should also work.

Comment: Should work then.  You only need one of SelectedItem and SelectedIndex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. For use in a Binding, your `GroupIndex` and `SelectedGroup` properties must be `public`.
2. Don't set `SelectedItem` and `SelectedIndex` at the same time.
3. If you prefer to set `SelectedItem`, that exact item (`SelectedGroup`) has to be contained in `Groups`.

Comment: Well spotted, same goes for SelectedGroup.

Comment: @Phil didn't spot the scrollbar :-)